# combobox: cuando selecione un item(1), abra una tabla del sqlite en el treeview, y cuando selecione otro item(2) abra otra tabla

Tags: python, tkinter, binding, tree, getitem

Todo comenzo cuando cree un combobox sencillamente lo quiero es que los items que se encuentran dentro del combo, cuando los selecione carguen una tabla sqlite, cada item dedicado a cada tabla.

Tengo un sqlite llamado **`compeletedlist.db`**.
En este caso cuando selecione el item(1) en el combobox cargue la tabla(Mymoon)
y cuando selecione el item(2) del mismo combo, cargue la tabla(Mysun)
toda la informacion de cada tabla se vea reflejada en un Treeview

Cuando yo seleciono el item(1) llama la funcion y me muestra la tabla en treeview todo bien hasta ahí.

> **El problema viene:** Cuando yo seleciono el item(2), item(3), o el item(4) llama la misma funcion y me muestra la misma tabla. la META es que cada item(1,2,3) me muestre diferentes tablas.

```
def connectmoon(*args):
        btn.config(state="active")
        Basedata = sqlite3.connect("src/compeletedlist.db")
        cur = Basedata.cursor()
        try:
            cur.execute(''' CREATE TABLE Mymoon (
                        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                        NUMBERS VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
                        DATE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                        CODE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                        COLUMN_A INT NOT NULL,COLUMN_B INT NOT NULL, COLUMN_C INT NOT NULL, COLUMN_D INT NOT NULL
                            ) ''')
            messagebox.showinfo("CREATE", "Your Base Data was succesfully create")
        except:
            messagebox.showinfo(title="CONECT", message="Mymoons is connect")
           showme()

def showme():
        Basedata = sqlite3.connect("src/compeletedlist.db")
        cur = Basedata.cursor()
        books = en1.get_children()
        for elements in books:
             en1.delete(elements)
        
        try:
            Basedata = sqlite3.connect("src/compeletedlist.db")
            cur = Basedata.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Mymoon")
            for row in cur:
                en1.insert("",0, text=row[1], values=(row[2]))
        except:
            pass
        
def clean():
    
        try:
            messagebox.askyesno(title="Clean", message="doyo want to clean")
            if 1 == YES: 
                books = en1.get_children()
                for elements in books:
                    en1.delete(elements)
                    NUMBERS.set("")
                    DATES.set("")
                    CODES.set("")
                else:
                    btn.config(state="disabled")
                    
        except:
            pass

tuple = [("MOON")]
list = Combobox(window, width=10, values=(tuple), state="readonly")
list.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", connectmoon)
list.place(x=5, y=30)
list.set("-Select-")

btn = Button(window, state="disabled" width=10, height=1, text="MOONS LIST", command = clean)
btn.place(x=10, y=10)
en1 = ttk.Treeview(fr2, xscrollcommand = ScrollbarH.set, 
                   yscrollcommand = ScrollbarV.set, columns=  ('#0','#1', '#2', '#3'))
tuple = [("MOON")]
list = Combobox(window, width=10, values=(tuple), state="readonly")
list.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", connectmoon)
list.place(x=5, y=30)
list.set("-Select-")
fr2 =LabelFrame(window, text="LIST")
fr2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, ipadx=2, ipady=55)
en1 = ttk.Treeview(fr2, xscrollcommand = ScrollbarH.set, 
                   yscrollcommand = ScrollbarV.set, columns=  ('#0','#1', '#2', '#3'))
en1.column('#0', width=5)
en1.column('#1', width=100, minwidth=100)
en1.column('#2', width=100, minwidth=100)
en1.column('#3', width=100, minwidth=100)
en1.heading("#1", text="DIGITS", anchor="center")
en1.heading("#2", text="DATES", anchor="center")
en1.heading("#3", text="CODE", anchor="center")
en1.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")
```